# about ln command : condition of cross-device

Tags: hard-link, ln

On **openSUSE Tumbleweed 20210606** with kernel **GNU/Linux 5.12.9-1-default**

I tried making a hard link of file from `/cust` to `~/backup`:

```
df /cust && df ~/backup && ln -P /cust/customization.tar ~/backup/
```

and get a result with error message:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      706523136 158883972 546393196  23% /
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      706523136 158883972 546393196  23% /home
ln: failed to create hard link '/home/luli/backup/customization.tar' => '/cust/customization.tar': Invalid cross-device link
```

Why it said that from `/dev/sda3` to `/dev/sda3` is `cross-device` and where can I get more details?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `ln -P /cust/customization.tar /luli/backup/` ? (assuming luli is under `/` )

Comment: @Archemar Yes it work for me. And lastly I find that btrfs devide ```/``` and ```/home``` to different partition on my . It seems that resetting partition scheme is better if indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ln` without options creates a hard link as documented [in the manual page for `link`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html), especially the section explaining error EXDEV, which contains the remark

> link() does not work across different mount points, even if the same
> filesystem is mounted on both

Although I realize that the paragraph below does not address the problem, I won't remove it from my answer. It might still be useful for some readers.

A hard link points to an inode number in the same filesystem and can therefore not be created across filesystems. You can use a symbolic link instead (-s option).

Comment: I think the question is about hard links in a filesystem mounted *twice* (perhaps using a bind mount). In principle, the kernel is "aware" that this is the same filesystem and thus the objection in your second paragraph does not apply.

Comment: @Kapil thanks. I admended the answer.